# logout using AJAX is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to logout on clicking this button

**html input**

```
<input type="button" value="logout" id="top-btn-logout" onclick="test()">
```

**my js file**

```
function test()
{
    $("#top-btn-logout").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/New%20folder/vigcheck.php?action=logout',
            success: function(data){
            alert(data);
                   //location.reload();
                //window.location.href = data;
            }
        });
    });


}  



check.php file.   

<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) == "logout" ){

    //$_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();  
    echo "logout";exit;
}?>
```

Comment: Why do you have an inline `onclick` handler that binds a jQuery event handler, that's asking for trouble.

Comment: why are you using ajax for this, also, your if-statement in your check.php file is incorrect.

Comment: Also, in PHP `isset` returns a boolean, not the value

Comment: @adeneo :Why do you have an inline onclick handler that binds a jQuery event handler, that's asking for trouble . ?then how to call the jQuery onclick

Comment: Certainly not from an onclick handler on the same element, you'll be rebinding that event everytime you click, sending multiple ajax requests etc.

Comment: Let me prove that, see how in this fiddle it just keeps adding up on each click -> **http://jsfiddle.net/uqq4ho8v/**

Comment: @adeneo:correct sir,thanks . i removed inline onclick.but session is not getting removed.can u help

Answer (score 1):

First use a proper get request using jquery ajax try

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/New%20folder/vigcheck.php',
            type: 'get',
            data:{action:'logout'},
            success: function(data){
            alert(data);
                   //location.reload();
                //window.location.href = data;
            }
        });
```

then check.php file. (you are combining conditions to check use both conditions separate)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action'])  && $_GET['action'] == "logout" ){

    //$_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();  
    echo "logout";exit;
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(isset($_GET['action']) == "logout" ){
```

This is incorrect because isset will return true and true != 'logout' so make it as

```
 if(isset($_GET['action'])){
   if($_GET['action']=="logout";
     //do whatever you wanna do
 }
```

Comment: :sir session is not destroying and it echo a parse error in check.php

Comment: there must be some syntax error and you are calling vigcheck.php in your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for returned data from check.php file on success of ajax request . After that redirect the user to your login page.

Comment: ya i changed .$("#top-btn-logout").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/New%20folder/vigcheck.php?action=logout', but it returns a parse error sir
                success: function(data){
    if(data == "logout")
    {
    alert(data);
        location.reload();
                    //window.location.href = data;
                }
    }
            });
        });

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

**JS File :**

```
function test()
{
    $("#top-btn-logout").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/New%20folder/vigcheck.php?action=logout',
            success: function(data){
            alert(data);
                   //location.reload();
                //window.location.href = data;
            },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (XMLHttpRequest.status === 401) {
          location.href = 'index.php';
        }
      }
        });
    });
}
```

**check.php :**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) == "logout" ){

header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");

}
?>
```